# unicode-math: Error in Typesetting an Equation "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [semantic nest size=500]"

Tags: equations, luatex, unicode-math, semantics

For the following equation, an error shows up

> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [semantic nest size=500]. ...(\vm\right)
>   & a_2\left(\vm\right) & \cdots &

while removing some elements from the array eliminates the error.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[tuenc,no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math,mathtools}
\newcommand\vm{\symup{x}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{a\left(x\right)}^T=
\{
\begin{array}{c c c c}
a_1\left(\vm\right) & a_2\left(\vm\right) & \cdots & a_m\left(\vm\right)
\end{array}%
\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

For the same equation, if `unicode-math` is removed, and the code changes accordingly, the error doesn't show up.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[tuenc,no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\vm{\mathrm{x}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{a\left(x\right)}^T=
\{
\begin{array}{c c c c}
a_1\left(\vm\right) & a_2\left(\vm\right) & \cdots & a_m\left(\vm\right)
\end{array}%
\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load `mathtools` first.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[tuenc,no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\newcommand\vm{\symup{x}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{a\left(x\right)}^T=
  \{
  \begin{array}{c c c c}
    a_1\left(\vm\right) & a_2\left(\vm\right) & \cdots & a_m\left(\vm\right)
  \end{array}%
  \}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: More precisely, `amsmath` should be loaded before `unicode-math`. Note that `\left` and `\right` are wrong here.

Comment: @egreg I thought `\left` and `\right` seemed wrong here, too. That is, it is not how I would have done it. But I wasn't sure it was wrong and not just different - I just don't know enough about typesetting maths. (But I guess I would think it wrong in logic, so probably that's the same?)

Comment: @egreg May I know the proper way to use `\left` and `\right`, and why my way is wrong? Thanks

Comment: @DiaaAbidou If you compare with and without `\left` and `\right`, you'll see that the spacing is different (and the additional space isn't wanted in general), but the size of the delimiters is the same.